# How to add data in objectStore on IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I can't add a simple id number to my indexedDB. This is what i'm doing:

In a service worker i have an eventListener of type `message`, then i receive a data to sending in another function to create an indexedDB and save the data passed:

```
function crearIDB(id) {
  var req = indexedDB.open("usuario", 1);
  req.onupgradeneeded = evt => {
    var db = evt.target.result;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("entidades")) {
      db.createObjectStore("entidades");
    }
  };
  req.onsuccess = evt => {
    console.log("Conectado a la BD");
    var db = evt.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("entidades");
    var store = tx.objectStore("entidades");
    store.add(id);
  };
```

The objectStore it is created correctly, but the id to add not.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what I had to do was that at the time of creating the objectStore, I had to add the object autoIncrement with value = true and the mode = readwrite

```
db.createObjectStore("entidades", { autoIncrement: true });
  req.onsuccess = evt => {
    console.log("Conectado a la BD");
    var db = evt.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction(["entidades"], "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("entidades");
    store.add(id);
  };
```